# Android Studio error the following clases not foud

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I use Android studio and make widgets using these tutorial

[App Widgets - Home Screen Widgets using App Widget Provider - Android Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jqNx-Xe1e8)

But I have a problem ... ... this error:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please post your code and logcat

Answer (score 2):

Switching the preview's API level from 23 to 21 fixes these error for most people. While waiting for a fix you could try it as well.

[image]